# Daily Cron expression Required

Tags: java

I want to create **Cron expression** for `5` days and run every day from starting date.

`start date :- 30-04-2017`

and

`End date:- 03-05-2017`

Run every day at `1:00PM`

Comment: Thanks for telling us. Have a nice day.

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000009DvvIAE

Comment: i need cron expression for 5 consecutive day after start date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try following lines of code,

```
SimpleTriggerFactoryBean simpleTriggerFactoryBean=new SimpleTriggerFactoryBean();  simpleTriggerFactoryBean.setJobDetail(job.getObject());  simpleTriggerFactoryBean.setStartTime(startDateTimeInMillis);  simpleTriggerFactoryBean.setRepeatInterval(24*60*60*1000);  simpleTriggerFactoryBean.setRepeatCount(5);  simpleTriggerFactoryBean.setName("name");  simpleTriggerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
```

I hope,this will resolve your problem.